# Warn on usage of problematic classes

Tags: java

I have just found a class of bugs in our system relating to the usage of `ZoneOffset.UTC` rather than `ZoneId.of("UTC")` with the new Java 8 `ZonedDateTime` API. Ideally to make sure these don't crop up again in future I would like to cause a warning on the usage of `ZoneOffset` any where in our code base.

If it was in our code I would `@Deprecated` annotate the class and that would solve the problem. However because it is in the JVM libraries I can't do this.

We have PMD, Checkstyle and Find bugs in the build system currently. If some thing else is needed that can probably be arranged but I would prefer a way with one of those.

Comment: Why do you care that the internals are using this property?  Better question:  if you know *which* internals are using this property, could you find a way to avoid their usage if it proves detrimental?

Comment: @Makoto I don't care if the internals are using this class. I care when our code uses this class as when DST changes ZoneOffsets don't keep up. There for using it in our tests and other code isn't a good idea, I could just recommend people don't use it but I'd rather some one got warned before they find a bug like the one I just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check style has a feature to do exactly what I needed.

The feature is called Import Control. To set it up you need to add the following as a child of the `TreeWalker` module. We already had a section for this. You may need to add it.

```
  <module name="ImportControl">
     <property name="file" value="import-control.xml"/>
  </module>
```

Make sure that the path to the file is valid for your project set up. You can set the `severity` property to `error` if you wish to cause these to be an error.

Next you need to create the `import-control.xml` file at the path entered in the config. It should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE import-control PUBLIC
      "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Import Control 1.1//EN"
      "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/import_control_1_1.dtd">
<import-control pkg="com.ijento.zeus">
   <allow class=".*" regex="true" />
   <disallow class="java.time.ZoneOffset" exact-match="true"/>
</import-control>
```

The "allow all" tag is required to allow all other classes. The disallow stops importing of the class you want to block. The order of these matters. It appears to evaluate the rules top down. If the "allow all" is at the bottom it allows every thing.

More details can be found here: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl